# Calling a custom function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, oop

I want to call a JavaScript function that I made after a JQuery event has been called. I defined a function called scrambleDot earlier like this `var scrambleDot = new function() 
{ //my code }`. Here's the code that I tried to use:

```
$('#reveal').click(function() {
    $('.cover').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
    $('#under').css({'visibility':'visible'});
})
$('#conceal').click(function() {
    $('scrambleDot');
})
```

})

Comment: it should be `var scrambleDot = function() { ... }`, no `new`, and to call it, just do `scrambleDot()`

Comment: please give more explanation

Comment: hey KyleMaclean, don't be discouraged by the downvotes. StackOverflow can be a tough crowd. Keep at it!

Comment: @MattGreer's right, don't be discouraged at all. It's a pity that beginner questions are downvoted so quickly... we all had them at some point.

Answer (score 4):

You have to call it just like:

```
scrambleDot();
```

To define a function, you don't need the `new` operator, so you should have:

```
var scrambleDot = function() { //my code }
```

If it still throws an error, it means it was defined in other scope. To make it globally accesible, do this when defining it:

```
window.scrambleDot = function() { //my code }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

1. We have to use `new` keyword, only when the function is used as a constructor for new Objects. So, the definition should not use `new`.

   ```
   var scrambleDot = function() { //my code }
   ```

   If the function need not be created dynamically, I would recommend

   ```
   function scrambleDot() {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. To invoke the function, simply do

   ```
   scrambleDot();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For that call the function instead of selecting an element as:

```
$('#reveal').click(function() {
    $('.cover').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
    $('#under').css({'visibility':'visible'});
})
$('#conceal').click(function() {
    scrambleDot();
});
```

And also, you write functions as:

```
function scrambleDot () {
  // your code 
}
```

It is a better practice than the variable one.